# Javascript/jQuery select the first anchor child in nested rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this code:

```
<ul>
  <li class="open-submenu"><a href="javascript:void(0)">HERE</a>            
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="open-submenu"><a href="javascript:void(0)">HERE</a>            
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>             
</ul>
```

I want to append, in javascript, a "+" char just next to the "HERE" text. I want also to add it inside a span element.

I tried `$('.open-submenu a:first').append("<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>");` but this affect only the first `open-submenu`;

I tried also `$('.open-submenu').append("<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>");` but this will affect ALL the anchors, even the nested anchors.

How can I append the span only inside the two `open-submenu`'s anchors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just target the `a` inside the class `.open-submenu` by doing it like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/estvwpvz/6/

```
$('.open-submenu > a').append("<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>");
```

Comment: even better because shorter.!Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `a` which is the direct child of  class submenu - `.open-submenu > a`:

```js
$('.open-submenu > a').append("<span class='open-submenu-sym'>+</span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="open-submenu"><a href="javascript:void(0)">HERE</a>            
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="open-submenu"><a href="javascript:void(0)">HERE</a>            
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
      <li><a href=#></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>             
</ul>
```

Comment: So does `$('.open-submenu > a')`

Comment: @mplungjan - indeed. I was overzealous a bit :)